# Custom file copy with Robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Where the text file contains a list of files, as below code, but it errors saying the `%%a` is an invalid parameter even though it correctly sees %%a as the file name.

Any way around this?

EDIT:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
  robocopy "%%~dpa" "Z:" "%%~nxa" /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

A file name argument of `ROBOCOPY` cannot include the path, whether absolute or relative. It should be just a name (with the extension). (Alternatively it can be a mask.)

If your text file contains full paths, you can extract names and extensions only using the `~nx` combined modifier:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
  robocopy "C:\Test1" "C:\Test2" "%%~nxa" /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30
)
```

Also, consider enclosing all your path/file names in double quotes, as you can see above, to avoid having issues with names containing spaces and/or special characters.

Comment: Can I remove file names from a fully qualified path? i.e. I have C:\Folder A\test.txt in the text file, and I want to end up with just C:\Folder A\ for the source, and Test.txt for the file (where %%~nxa does now)

Comment: `%%~dpa` will extract the drive and path, without name and extension. You can read more about these modifiers in the `for` command's built-in help (`for /?`, they are listed nearer the end).

Comment: I thought that, however, see my edit, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Seems to do with the trailing backslash. Please post a new question as that is an entirely different problem from the one you asked originally.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388400/batch-for-loop-removing-file-from-folder-names