# Batch For Loop - removing file from folder names

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, modifier

I have a text file which contains things like:

"C:\Folder A\Test.txt"

I need to copy certain files and their respective containers to a new directory from a directory, but only those files I specify and their parent folder structures.

In my batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
  robocopy "%%~dpa" "Z:\" "%%~nxa" /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30
)
pause
```

However, it fails the robocopy, probably to do with the trailing backslash. The Source gets mixed up and shows both the folder and the Z:. This means t he file name from `%%~nxa` is then part of the destination rather than the file to copy.  Any ideas?

Comment: Tell please if C:\audit\test.txt lines are sorounded by doublequotes?

Comment: Yes they are "" quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is treated as an escape character in this case because it immediately precedes the closing `"`. If you append a `.` to the path, the result will be the same path but the backslash will no longer precede the closing `"` and therefore will not be treated as an escape character for the ending quote.

In the example you've posted both the source and target paths end with a `\`. Therefore you'll need to add a `.` to both:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
  robocopy "%%~dpa." "Z:\." "%%~nxa" /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

/MIR will copy the directory structure recursively, even directories that do not conatin files names in test.txt.
Please do not use double quotes for first parameter.
/R:1000000 /W:30 /COPY:DAT are default values, so no need to set tehm explicitely.

Please try the folowing code:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
  robocopy %%~dpa "Z:\" "%%~nxa" /E /PURGE /MIR 
)
pause
```

If you're using spaces and/or special symbols in file paths, you can try the code below taht uses copy comand:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (C:\audit\test.txt) do (
    if not exist "Z:\%%~pa" mkdir "Z:\%%~pa"
    copy /Y "%%~a" "Z:\%%~pnxa"
)
```

Comment: This may indeed solve the problem, but only if the paths do not contain special characters or spaces.

Comment: File paths are quoted (as it is mentioned in article comments), so no fear of spaces. Spacial characters - maybe yes. Maybe it doesn't worth to worry about them if user doesn't use files with special characters.

Comment: The tilde `~` causes removal of quotes, so if there are spaces anywhere in the path, `%%~dpa` without quotes will be treated as two (or more) parameters.

Comment: Sorry @Andriy M, you're right. Only hope is user doesn't use paths containing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the main problem I face is keeping the permissions and timestamps, hence the robocopy.